# discord.js v12 Event handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am working on an event handler and a line is getting an error. i am not sure if i am missing something with the new release of djs v12 may have changed .run

Edit: for a ready.js

Error: 
`TypeError: eventFunction.execute is not a function`

code:

```
fs.readdir('./Events/', (err, files) => { 
    if (err) return console.error(err); 
    files.forEach(file => {
        const eventFunction = require(`./Events/${file}`); 
        if (eventFunction.disabled) return; 

        const event = eventFunction.event || file.split('.')[0]; 
        const emitter = (typeof eventFunction.emitter === 'string' ? client[eventFunction.emitter] : eventFunction.emitter) || client; 
        const once = eventFunction.once; 


        try {
            emitter[once ? 'once' : 'on'](event, (...args) => eventFunction.run(...args)); 
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.stack); 
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT: 
image to show contents of even file:
[image]
error is clearly something to do with the .run

Comment: What's inside `./events`? Could you please give an example of one of the events there?

Comment: added image to post

Comment: Be careful, the folder you are reading is `Events` and you are using `/events/` when concatenating

Comment: tried that. still get `TypeError: eventFunction.run is not a function`

Comment: From the image, it seems like `ready.js` isn't exporting anything (it just has `console.log("test");`. Make sure you're exporting the `run` function (and all of the other properties you use) using `module.exports = {run() {/* code */}, disabled: /* something */}` etc.